# How do I use .htaccess to redirect a directory name, but not a page name?

Tags: .htaccess

So the site I'm editing has both `/Drug-Charges` as well as Drug-Charges.html.

How do I redirect one, but not the other? Everything I'm doing seems to affect both.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the dollar sign:

```
RewriteRule ^/Drug-Charges$ /something-else
```

The `^` sign means this is the beginning of a string while `$` is the marker for the end of a string.